# In GitHub -How to de-merge the branch from master?

Tags: git, github

I am Using GitHub for version Control

Unfortunately, I merged the branch with master using the below code

```
git checkout master
git merge updating-users
```

Now, I just want to know , How to de-merge the branch(updating-users) from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within `master`, do a `git reset --hard #commit_id` to the most recent good commit on `master`. (You can get the commit id by going `git log`.) The `updating-users` branch will be unaffected.

If you've already pushed the merge to GitHub, you'll have to push again and pass `--force` since you've overwritten the history.

Answer (score 0):

[How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/git-revert-to-previous-commit-how)

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html:

> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the
>   related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record
>   them. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications
>   from the HEAD commit). Note: git revert is used to record some new
>   commits to reverse the effect of some earlier commits (often only a
>   faulty one). If you want to throw away all uncommitted changes in your
>   working directory, you should see git-reset(1), particularly the
>   --hard option. If you want to extract specific files as they were in another commit, you should see git-checkout(1), specifically the git
>   checkout  --  syntax. Take care with these
>   alternatives as both will discard uncommitted changes in your working
>   directory.

If you want to undo only one commit on the master:

```
git revert #commit_id_to_undo
```

The git revert is similar to the functionality of [`patch -R file.patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch).